# Pandas Join Rows If Time Is Continuous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that shows when employees want to take time off. The Event Title is always in the format of "User Off" along with the specific time if it is not an all day event. Here is a snippet of the dataframe `df`:

```
            Event Title      Start        End Employee
UserA Off (07:00-12:00) 2023-05-08 2023-05-09    UserA
UserA Off (12:00-15:30) 2023-05-08 2023-05-09    UserA
             UserB Off  2023-05-10 2023-05-11    UserB
UserC Off (08:00-10:30) 2023-05-30 2023-05-31    UserC
UserC Off (10:30-16:30) 2023-05-30 2023-05-31    UserC
UserD Off (09:30-10:00) 2023-05-10 2023-05-11    UserD
UserE Off (13:00-16:00) 2023-06-02 2023-06-03    UserE
UserE Off (07:30-13:00) 2023-06-02 2023-06-03    UserE
```

Users A, C, and E have 2 lines for the same start and end date but the times are continuous (this is because they pull from multiple vacation buckets like Vacation and Floating Holiday). What is the best way to combine these rows if the time is continuous?

Here is the first query I created to only display users that have multiple entries on the same day

```
test = df.groupby(by=['Start','End','Employee']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

            Event Title      Start        End Employee
UserA Off (07:00-12:00) 2023-05-08 2023-05-09    UserA
UserA Off (12:00-15:30) 2023-05-08 2023-05-09    UserA
UserC Off (08:00-10:30) 2023-05-30 2023-05-31    UserC
UserC Off (10:30-16:30) 2023-05-30 2023-05-31    UserC
UserE Off (13:00-16:00) 2023-06-02 2023-06-03    UserE
UserE Off (07:30-13:00) 2023-06-02 2023-06-03    UserE
```

Now I need to see if the times are continuous (i.e. if the first time off on a day ends at noon, then the start time of for this individual should start at noon). It can be assumed it is an all-day absence if it is continuous.

My original idea was to iterate over each dataframe  `df.groupby(by=['Start','End','Employee'])`, sort by `Event Title` and then do `iterrows()` on each row and parse if `Event Title.str.split('-')[1]` equals `Event Title.str.split('(')[1].str.split('-')[0]` of the next row, but this seems very inefficient.

My end result would be the original dataframe `df` but have the continuous times be joined like so:

```
             Event Title      Start        End Employee
              UserA Off 2023-05-08 2023-05-09    UserA
              UserB Off 2023-05-10 2023-05-11    UserB
              UserC Off 2023-05-30 2023-05-31    UserC
UserD Off (09:30-10:00) 2023-05-10 2023-05-11    UserD
              UserE Off 2023-06-02 2023-06-03    UserE
```

Comment: Don't you want to know the hours `UserA`, `UserC` and `UserE` were off, given it doesn't appear to be the whole day?

Comment: @Nick not for my use case, this is used to create calendar events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the data you provided, here's how you can join absences which are continuous, using `groupby` in combination with `shift` as well as some `regex` to extract the necessary information from the `Event Title` column:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Event Title': [
        'UserA Off (07:00-12:00)', 'UserA Off (12:00-15:30)', 'UserB Off',
        'UserC Off (08:00-10:30)', 'UserC Off (10:30-16:30)', 'UserD Off (09:30-10:00)',
        'UserE Off (13:00-16:00)', 'UserE Off (07:30-13:00)'
        ],
    'Start': [
        '2023-05-08', '2023-05-08', '2023-05-10', '2023-05-30',
        '2023-05-30', '2023-05-10', '2023-06-02', '2023-06-02'
        ],
    'End': [
        '2023-05-09', '2023-05-09', '2023-05-11', '2023-05-31',
        '2023-05-31', '2023-05-11', '2023-06-03', '2023-06-03'
        ],
    'Employee': [
        'UserA', 'UserA', 'UserB', 'UserC',
        'UserC', 'UserD', 'UserE', 'UserE'
        ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Extract Start and End Hour
df['_time_off_start_hour'] = df['Event Title'].str.extract(r'(?<=\()(\d\d:\d\d)')
df['_time_off_end_hour'] = df['Event Title'].str.extract(r'(\d\d:\d\d)(?=\))')

# Sort Values
df.sort_values(by=['Start','End','Employee', '_time_off_start_hour'], inplace=True)

# Compute Helper Columns
df['_time_off_start_next_event'] = (
    df
    .groupby(['Start','End','Employee'])['_time_off_start_hour']
    .shift(-1)
)
df['_time_off_end_previous_event'] = (
    df
    .groupby(['Start','End','Employee'])['_time_off_end_hour']
    .shift(1))
df['_continuous_time'] = (
    df.loc[:, '_time_off_start_next_event']
    == df.loc[:, '_time_off_end_hour']
)
df['_duplicated_row'] = (
    df.loc[:, '_time_off_end_previous_event']
    == df.loc[:, '_time_off_start_hour']
)

# Modify first row where continuous pair was found
df.loc[df['_continuous_time'], 'Event Title'] = df['Employee'] + " Off"
# Drop second row of each continuous pair
df = df.loc[~df['_duplicated_row'], :]

# Drop internal columns
cols_to_drop = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("_")]
df.drop(columns=cols_to_drop, inplace=True)

# Show results
print(df.sort_values(by='Employee').to_markdown(index=False))
```

Returns:

```
| Event Title             | Start      | End        | Employee   |
|:------------------------|:-----------|:-----------|:-----------|
| UserA Off               | 2023-05-08 | 2023-05-09 | UserA      |
| UserB Off               | 2023-05-10 | 2023-05-11 | UserB      |
| UserC Off               | 2023-05-30 | 2023-05-31 | UserC      |
| UserD Off (09:30-10:00) | 2023-05-10 | 2023-05-11 | UserD      |
| UserE Off               | 2023-06-02 | 2023-06-03 | UserE      |
```